# Xamarin Android UI Automation with UIAutomator2 Driver for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-uiautomator

I am working on adding UI Automation to Xamarin.Android app using Appium **UIAotomator2** driver for Android.  Reading this documentation http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/index.html, I am suprised to see that it says it requires Java 7.

When I issue `java -version` on my MacBookPro, I get that my java version is 1.8.0_131.

Will Appium UiAutomator2 driver for Android work with java 1.8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work on Java 8 without any issues.

[UIAutomator2 server](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server) is written in Java 7, so requirement is actually Java 7+.